# how to display form content after php processing

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Im creating a forum for a little project of mine.

So far I have been able to get the form contents and use php to process (YES I HAVE NOT ACCOUNTED FOR SQL INJECTION).

Anyway, the php code is as follows:

**test.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["add"])){
    // "Save Changes" clicked
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'main_database';

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username , $password,$db);
    
    if (!$conn){
        die("unable to connect");
    }

    $dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO threads (title,author,date_posted,post) VALUES ('$title', 2, '$dt', '$message')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
      
    mysqli_close($conn);

    header('Location: http://127.0.0.1:5500/RuneScape_website/RS.com/aff/runescape/forums/ForumThread/~tm10CE.html');
}   
?>
```

Now what I really want to do, is after this data has been saved to the database, I want to display the newly created blog comment to the direct page on load up. For example, When you click submit, the comment should appear in the directed html page.

The only way I think about it, is that I need either javascript to create a new attribute and append it to the list of existing attributes (e.g. ), or in the php create the div and use javascript/JQuery to access the php file and collect the html.

So I want the `$title` and `$message` to be used in the html page where its directed to.

A real example is like stack overflow. After I write an answer the page appends my response. This is what I want to achieve.

I'm curious how to go about this. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please rewrite the code first to use prepared statements and then update the question?

Comment: @Dharman of course! I am just trying something out first. Im not trying to do database stuff yet, that comes after figuring this out.

Comment: before the redirect, get the last insert id, then send that in your redirect as a query string. The page that is getting the redirect checks for that parameter and queries the database for that id.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to know which forum page this submitted comment belongs to?

If you add a column to threads table and store the name of the forum page in it (in this case: ~tm10CE.html), then from your html page, you can make an ajax call to a php file and include the name of the page as a querystring value.  Inside the php file, query the threads table for the name of the page and return all the entries related to that page.

Comment: I agree, I was thinking that. My issue I am having, is normally tutorials online are posting with ajax to the php file in the html file the form was sent. What I am trying to do, is when in the html file that the submits the form, then php processes it, I want another html file to gain access to those variables.

Comment: Let's call the page containing the form, "Page A", and the final html page that the user lands on, "Page B".  When the user submits the form on Page A, you need to save the name of Page B in a column in the threads table along with the other submitted values.  Then, when the user lands on Page B, make an ajax call and pass the name of the page in that call.  The php file will use the name of the page you pass to pull the correct information from the database and return it so that you can display it on Page B.